# Namespace 'jasmine' has no exported member 'SpyObj'

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm trying to create a spy object for my tests:

```
let spy: jasmine.SpyObj<GeneralService>;
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting this error when running `ng test`:

```
Namespace 'jasmine' has no exported member 'SpyObj'
```

In addition, WebStorm marks `SpyObj` as unresolved variable.

Here is `devDependencies` from my `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.7.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.36",
    "@types/node": "7.0.27",
    "jasmine": "~2.4.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "4.16.2",
    "ts-node": "1.3.0",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "2.6.2"
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

I refer to Angular testing docs:
https://angular.io/guide/testing

```
let masterService: MasterService;
let valueServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<ValueService>;

beforeEach(() => {
  const spy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ValueService', ['getValue']);

  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    // Provide both the service-to-test and its (spy) dependency
    providers: [
      MasterService,
      { provide: ValueService, useValue: spy }
    ]
  });
  // Inject both the service-to-test and its (spy) dependency
  masterService = TestBed.get(MasterService);
  valueServiceSpy = TestBed.get(ValueService);
});
```

I end up configure spy as `any`:

```
 let spy: any;
```

Comment: can you try let spy: jasmine.createSpyObj<GeneralService>;

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321307/what-is-the-difference-between-createspy-and-createspyobj

Comment: @HardikPatel Your link doesn't answer what type should be used instead

Answer (score 1):

I had working Jasmine tests with spy objects and one day it just stopped to work in my environment (but the same commit was fine in CI pipeline) with the very same error as yours (both from *ng test* invoked from terminal and from IDE intelli sense).

Restarting and even upgrading the IDE (*Jet Brains Rider*) didn't help, so I just removed *node_modules* directory and invoked *npm install* again and this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Your jasmine version does not have support for `SpyObj` type which was introduced in the later version.**

Try updating `jasmine-core` and `@types/jasmine` from the `package.json` to the latest stable version or try with `"jasmine-core": "2.8.0", @types/jasmine": "2.6.0"` should work fine without the errors.

Answer (score 0):

### Try This:

I had the same problem message which was connected to another problem message:

File './node_modules/@types/jasmine/ts3.1/index.d.ts' not found.
The file is in the program because:
Entry point for implicit type library 'jasmine' with packageId '@types/jasmine/ts3.1/index.d.ts@3.5.10'

The weird thing was, that I actually had this file in my node_modules.

**The solution was painfully easy:**

**Restart (and update) VS Code.**

Everything worked again without any problem messages.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was because typescript used jasmine from jasmine-marbles. This was because my tsconfig.json had typeRoots specified. After removing, it started using types from @types/jasmine.

TypeRoots documentation:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots